# Ajax ASP.net ModalPopupExtender won't display the panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I am working on an internal company tool for data entry.  The ASP page displays a complete list of all items previously entered.  At the top is a button to enter new jobs which will pop up a modal popup, in theory.  The panel which is used for new jobs is also used when modifying existing jobs, but the popup is called with a unique `ModalPopupExtender` instance.

When calling the Update ModalPopupExtender, the panel shows correctly, including automatically populating the controls with that job's details.  However, the New Job button does not display the panel.

I have tried to use automatic control (built into the AJAX toolkit), manual control of the popup on the backend with the .show and .hide methods, and using a Javascript client script which should find and popup the required panel.  In all of these cases, the list of jobs is hidden behind a layer of gray, but the panel remains hidden.

What am I missing?

ASPX code:

```
<asp:Button runat = "server" ID = "btnNewJobDummy" CssClass = "invisible" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeNewJob" runat="server" TargetControlID = "btnNewJobDummy" PopupControlID = "pnlJobEntry" BackgroundCssClass = "modalBackground" />
```

Code behind:

```vb
Private Sub btnNewJob_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNewJob.Click
    Session("Mode") = "Add"
    Session("TagMode") = "NewJob"
    tbAddDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
    imgFeaturedPhoto.ImageUrl = "~/JobImages/not-available.jpg"
    tbAddCenterStoneQty.Text = "1"
    Dim dtCenterStone As New DataTable
    Dim dtImages As New DataTable
    Session("CenterStones") = Nothing
    dtCenterStone = Session("CenterStones")
    gvCenterStones.DataSource = dtCenterStone
    gvCenterStones.DataBind()
    gvCenterStonesEdit.DataSource = dtCenterStone
    gvCenterStonesEdit.DataBind()
    Session("Images") = Nothing
    dtImages = Session("Images")
    lvPhotoGallery.DataSource = dtImages
    lvPhotoGallery.DataBind()
    'lvPhotoGallery.FindControl("btnMakeDefault").Visible = False
    ddlAddCenterStoneSource.SelectedValue = "2"
    'btnJobEntryCancel.Visible = False
    btnJobEntryCancel.CssClass = "invisible"
    'btnNewJobCancel.Visible = True
    btnNewJobCancel.CssClass = "visible"
    ResetTagPanel()
    Session("mpeNewJob") = "show"
    ShowModalPopups("mpeNewJob", "show")
    'mpeNewJob.Show()
End Sub
```